# Can you adjust the width of a single stacked bar chart with ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to make the bar chart from the code below narrower.

```
df <- data.frame(
      names = LETTERS[1:4],
      vals = c(25, 20, 30, 25))

ggplot(df,aes(1,y=vals,fill=names)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity")
```

I have tried to fix this using `width` in the ggplot command, but it seems that this only works if there are multiple bars. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Convert the `1` to a factor and change the width

```
ggplot(df, aes(as.factor(1), vals, fill = names)) +
  geom_col(width = .3)
```

Note that instead of `geom_bar` with argument `stat = identity` you can use `geom_col`.

[image]